# Android update AppWidget after Volley service

Tags: android, android-widget, android-volley

The Configuration Activity for my widget starts a service to make an http request and update the widget views. I can update the views from the service just fine (see below), but why is it I cannot update them from the response handler?

```
public class TestService extends Service {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "TestService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service started");

        final Context context = this;
        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_activity);
        final ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WidgetActivity.class);

        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        final String url = "http://google.com";

        final AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        final int[] ids = manager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        // DOES NOT WORK
                        views.setTextViewText(R.id.last_updated_text, "After Request");
                        manager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(ids, views);

                        // ALSO DOES NOT WORK
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                views.setTextViewText(R.id.last_updated_text, "After Request");
                                manager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(ids, views);
                            }
                        });

                        // ALSO DOES NOT WORK
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                views.setTextViewText(R.id.last_updated_text, "After Request");
                                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        );

        queue.add(request);

        // WORKS
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.last_updated_text, "Before Request");
        manager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget(ids, views);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I restarted my device and now the following seems to work just fine:

```
StringRequest priceRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Result: " + response);

                views.setTextViewText(R.id.last_updated_text, "After Request");
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);

            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update android views with UI thread only.

Try updating widget in UI thread like.

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(...runnable)
```

Comment: Updated my question to include your code, still does not seem to work :/

Comment: I added that to my question as well, no dice. That is how I was originally attempting to update the widget.

Comment: Did you debug this service, is it alive when response arrive?

Comment: Restarted my device and now it seems to work fine even without using an additional handler or anything... weird.

Comment: Really weird :)

Answer (score 1):

When we updater AppWidget data we need to call this method -> notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(int[] appWidgetIds, int viewId).

```
 manager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(ids, views);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got it. Just restarted my device and the code seemed fine. I will try this if I have any future issues with it